# Mono and TransactionScope

Tags: .net, mono, cross-platform, base-class-library

TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption for the TransactionScope was added in .NET 4.5.1 and seems has no implementation on Mono(3.8.0).

So I'm looking for a correct workaround or maybe some kind of a "polyfill".

P.S.: Seems mono development process is closed for any feature requests. So I didn't find a way to report about this feature.

Comment: Missing implementations can be logged on Xamarin's issue tracker: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked for [a feature](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23050) on Xamarin's issue tracker quite long ago. Seems it's not a priority for Xamarin's team.

Answer (score 0):

It is available in Mono source code:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Transactions/System.Transactions/TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.cs

But it is strange to see that issue as NEW :)